# Will upgrading my USB-to-ethernet adapter to USB 3.0 make any difference?

Tags: usb-3, usb-network-adapter

My super-slim ultrabook has one USB 2.0, one USB 3.0 port, and zero ethernet ports. It came with a USB 2.0-to-ethernet adapter and it works just fine in either port. I have noticed that USB 3.0 ethernet adapters are available.

Will upgrading to a USB 3.0 adapter possibly offer a faster connection? Are ethernet connections over a certain speed being bottle necked by the limitations of the USB 2.0 connection?

Comment: *"It came with a passive USB 2.0-to-ethernet adapter"* -- Not likely that it is "passive".  There is very likely a SoC (system on chip) that has a 32-bit processor with RAM and ROM in that adapter.  These active electronic devices will draw power from the USB host.

Comment: If you connect to a Gigabit LAN, then you could see a benefit from a USB_3.0-to-Gigabit_Ethernet adapter.

Comment: @sawdust Thank you for pointing that out. It doesn't have its own power supply so I assumed it was passive forgetting that it draws power from the USB port.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this depends on your internet connection. You can check your download (and upload) speeds at speedtest.net.

Since USB 2.0 has a maximum speed of 480Mbit/s, your internet speed will have to be faster than this to make it useful to get a USB 3.0 adapter (which supports up to 4.8Gbit/s).

Comment: I like the looks of those numbers and, at $25, I think the USB 3.0 adapter is worth a shot. Thanks.

Comment: @PFitz I think you missed the point, if your internet you are currintly paying for is 50 Mbit/s going from 2.0 to 3.0 will make no diffrence. You need to bet getting more than 480 Mbit/s from your ISP for there to be a difference.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I understand what he is saying and I realize that my home internet connection isn't nearly fast enough to take advantage of USB 3.0's capabilities. But I often have my computer at universities or offices that have higher connections speeds. Do you know whether or not any institutional connection speeds typically exceed 480 Mbit/s?

Comment: Most new networks are 1000 Mbits/s, so if you are transferring a lot of information and have fast hard disks then you could increase your speed.

Comment: Plus you can benefit from higher speeds within your own LAN. With a gigabit router, you could connect your laptop(s) and desktop(s) at home and get speeds that *would* be faster than 480Mbps.

Answer (score 2):

USB 2.0 only does half-duplex, so you'll get more latency. USB 3.0 can do full duplex. If you are doing something like gaming that is latency sensitive, it's probably worth finding a full-duplex solution (make sure your USB 3.0 device can do full duplex). Bandwidth wise, you'll need a wide pipe to the internet to need USB 3.0 over 2.0 based on USB max throughput.